# What can I use IdentityServer4 Oauth on Grafana

Tags: c#, grafana

I'm using `IdentityServer4` to set up one Server
and `InMemoryConfiguration.cs` is to initialize my data

**InMemoryConfiguration.cs**

```
new Client
{
   ClientId = "client.api.service",
   ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("clientsecret".Sha256()) },
   RedirectUris = { $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/login/generic_oauth" ,
                    $"http://10.228.51.221:56458/signin-oidc",
                    $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/signin-oidc",
                    $"http://localhost:12415/signin-oidc"},
   AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
   AllowedScopes = new [] {
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
           "agentservice", "clientservice", "productservice"
   },
},
new Client
{
   ClientId = "product.api.service",
   ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("productsecret".Sha256()) },
   RedirectUris = { $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/login/generic_oauth" ,
                    $"http://10.228.51.221:56458/signin-oidc",
                    $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/signin-oidc",
                    $"http://localhost:12415/signin-oidc"},
   AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
   AllowedScopes = new [] {
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
           "agentservice", "clientservice", "productservice"
   },
 },
 new Client
 {
    ClientId = "agent.api.service",
    ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("agentsecret".Sha256()) },
    RedirectUris = { $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/login/generic_oauth" ,
                     $"http://10.228.51.221:56458/signin-oidc",
                     $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/signin-oidc",
                     $"http://localhost:12415/signin-oidc"},
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
    AllowedScopes = new [] {
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
           "agentservice", "clientservice", "productservice"
    },
 },
 new Client
 {
    ClientId = "cas.mvc.client.implicit",
    ClientName = "CAS MVC Web App Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    RedirectUris = { $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/login/generic_oauth" ,
                     $"http://10.228.51.221:56458/signin-oidc",
                     $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/signin-oidc",
                     $"http://localhost:12415/signin-oidc",
                     $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/login"},
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/login/generic_oauth",
                               $"http://localhost:12415/signin-oidc",
                               $"http://10.228.51.220:3000",
                               $"http://10.228.51.220:3000/login"},
     AllowedScopes = new [] {
             IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
             IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
             IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
             "agentservice", "clientservice", "productservice"
     },
     AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true // can return access_token to this client

 },
```

But it can't work if I use `Grafana` click `Oauth` login. 
It show

Sorry, there was an error :

> unauthorized_client Request Id: 0HLU6VUML3LN5:00000002

I Setting the `RedirectUris` but it can't fix that.
What can I fix that?

Comment: What are the credentials you're trying?

Comment: I don't know credentials ?
What can i setting credentials?

Comment: I use this https://iter01.com/425800.html teaching and I can use MVCClient login but I change to Grafana it not work

Comment: What can i use authorization_code?